# Which log backup to apply first during recovery?

Tags: sql-server, restore, recovery

During recovery, I have restored the latest full backup, followed by the latest differential backup.

Last Full backup had ran on Thursday 9.15pm. Last Differential backup had run on Sunday 3.15am. Log backups run every hour starting from 12am. Last Log backups ran today at 10am. Presently it is 10.11am. I have done tail log backup.

Which is the first log backup that I should restore after the differential restore completes? The one from Sunday 4am?

Comment: Try it out and see if it works if you use the TLOG from 3am. What does the GUI recommend?

Answer (score 1):

When you restore a transaction log after restoring a full and/or differential, the transaction log you restore can include the time covered by that full/differential, and that will be handled by the restore process, skipping already committed transactions from the backup. Then, you just need the log that covers the time that's not in the full/differential. In your case, if there was a 3am transaction log backup, covering the time between 2am & 3am, you don't need that one, it's in the differential that covers up to 3:15am. Instead, you start with the 4am transaction backup that covers the time between 3am & 4am, even though fifteen minutes of that is covered by the differential. You proceed in order from there up to the tail log backup. Always in order. You can't skip around, 9am, then 7am, won't work. You'll get errors and the restore will not happen.